# Keeping books in an organized manner without using a bookshelf

Tags: home, storage, organization, books

I was looking to buy a bookshelf to store my books until after I saw that my neighbor friend bookshelf was attacked by white ants secretly, where he found almost half of the books were damaged. So, I was thinking not to use bookshelves rather something different to store my books in a safe and organized manner.

I was thinking to take advantage the walls of my room, like making a support in a type so that books can be kept efficiently.

I ran out of ideas, it would be very much helpful if one could help me in this.

Comment: So you basically don't want them to be in the open air?

Comment: Do you have white ants? Are there some traps you can simply keep around to stop the ants from becoming a problem?

Comment: @arieljannai first I donot want to buy a new cupboard since I have 2 of them now, I want to create something different and new to keep my books in an organized manner, like just as an idea - a wooden plank fixed to the wall horizontally and i can then keep my books there

Comment: it can be in open air, I have no problem with that

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean they attack very secretly and i donot want to take risks

Comment: As long as the books are in the open air and not in a sealed container, ants can get to them. It doesn't matter what type of structure you use. You need to get rid of the termites. http://www.killthetermites.com/do-termites-eat-books.htm

Comment: Hobbes is right. Even shelves attached to the wall are vulnerable. The only really secure way would be to enclosed them within something airtight. The next best would be shelves suspended by metal rods from the ceiling. Then the wall mounted shelves. If I had termites, I’d worry more about my house than books though.

Comment: You'll need to choose - you say you don't have problem with the books in the open air, but you don't want the ants to get in there. So it'll be probably better to use a close storage for the books, or take care of the ants.

Comment: a plank attached to the wall **is** a bookshelf. I mean that's the definition of a shelf. Maybe you want to avoid a bookcase?

Comment: You wrote that you ran out of ideas. Please include one or more of those ideas you rejected before you came to lifehacks.SE and why. Edit your question to include additional information that would be very much helpful if you could help us in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use materials for your book storage unit that are attractive, strong, and of no interest to ants at all.

**Glass book shelves in a tubular steel frame** is available in a variety of styles. The style that you find most attractive might also be referred to as a **glass display case**. Different versions of ones are also referred to as a(n) **glass etagére** (French). A Web image search will reveal many.

This might work for you where products made from wood fibres, pegs, and glue won't since these materials are the favourite food of white ants (aka termites). You can't stop the ants with one of these; but, you'll be able to see any sight-seers creeping around your delicious books.

One of the most effective deterrents for these little guys, who are a relatives of the cockroach, is borax powder. Putting the feet of your bookcase in containers of borax will discourage scouts from climbing up to where your books are stored. Take precautions to avoid any contact with the walls or any other possible access.

Also keep in mind that if white ants (termites) nibble as far as your book collection, the frame of your house must look like Swiss cheese and might be structurally affected. The foundation in your home near damp areas is the first place where an attack of white ants begins. If you suspect damage from ants, it would be worth a small investment for an inspector to find out before major damage has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be (a potential attack of) ants, and not using bookshelves. Just put ant poison where you plan to store your books (choose the appropriate type, so that  you don't get it on the books themselves).